# ASP.net any code behind changes delete sessions

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm developing a website on my local server for testing.  Every time I make a code behind change it seems to delete my session on the server and I have to re login again.  So I end up logging in about 100 times a day.

Any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to your application web.config `<compilation debug="true">` You need to set it false, or just disable login functionality in development environment, which I don't recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You can also replicate the "Keep me logged in" functionality you see in many sites. If the appropriate checkbox is ticked then log-in info is saved in a cookie. If you use the built in Microsoft form authentication you can do this quite easily.